# Problems in accessing S3 via AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to get and S3 object size via Java AWS SDK (v2), and send it back via HTTP response (this is all inside a HTTP Server using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`). But it doesn't work and shows me the following debug messages.

What's going wrong here? Am I missing anything?

```
        AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                AdapterMain.ACCESS_KEY,
                AdapterMain.SECRET_KEY);

        s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(region)
                                    .endpointOverride(URI.create(AdapterMain.S3server))
                                   .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                                   .build();
                    //TODO
                    HeadObjectRequest getObjectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(bucketName).key("FILES/"+getMD5(id)+"/FILES/"+id+"/"+id+".txt").build();

                    HeadObjectResponse objectHead = s3Client.headObject(getObjectRequest);
                    long size = objectHead.contentLength();
                    System.out.println("=================================="+size);
                    response=size+"";
                    he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
```

And here are the logs:

```
18:44:14.898 [HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain - Creating an interceptor chain that will apply interceptors in the following order: [software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.interceptor.HttpChecksumRequiredInterceptor@62ec69e1, software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.interceptor.HelpfulUnknownHostExceptionInterceptor@1d17dde7, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.EnableChunkedEncodingInterceptor@339b31af, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.DisableDoubleUrlEncodingInterceptor@3d96c2f6, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.EnableTrailingChecksumInterceptor@3cb417c4, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.CreateMultipartUploadRequestInterceptor@1f6f0d50, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.GetObjectInterceptor@7513515b, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.AsyncChecksumValidationInterceptor@7e99ac7d, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.EndpointAddressInterceptor@620f9e5d, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.ExceptionTranslationInterceptor@56d0ac1, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.GetBucketPolicyInterceptor@6a1b0abe, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.PutObjectInterceptor@5952b9c4, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.SyncChecksumValidationInterceptor@473129c5, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.DecodeUrlEncodedResponseInterceptor@2ae718e0, software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.CreateBucketInterceptor@181bb9f8]
18:44:14.939 [HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain - Interceptor 'software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.EndpointAddressInterceptor@620f9e5d' modified the message with its modifyHttpRequest method.
18:44:14.967 [HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Sending Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=HEAD, protocol=https, host=file-store.s3-server.dcstore.company.net, port=443, encodedPath=/FILES/f13e/FILES/id_1234/id_1234.txt, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent], queryParameters=[])
18:44:14.978 [HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.Aws4Signer - AWS4 String to sign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20210305T014414Z
20210305/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
9bfed5fd14903f65ac34647985e2c8a4bbe0fbf311982cfbeb2e44b2b58a2390
18:44:14.991 [HTTP-Dispatcher] WARN software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.utils.ApacheUtils - NoSuchMethodException was thrown when disabling normalizeUri. This indicates you are using an old version (< 4.5.8) of Apache http client. It is recommended to use http client version >= 4.5.9 to avoid the breaking change introduced in apache client 4.5.7 and the latency in exception handling. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1919 for more information
18:44:15.098 [HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory - socket.getSupportedProtocols(): [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2Hello], socket.getEnabledProtocols(): [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
18:44:15.099 [HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory - TLS protocol enabled for SSL handshake: [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, TLSv1.3]
18:44:15.506 [HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.net.SdkSslSocket - created: file-store.s3-server.dcstore.company.net/10.111.111.20:443
```

Comment: Random q, but  have you updated your apache client?

Comment: I see a message showing there...but where is Apache client used?! Doesn't it come with the SDK itself?

Comment: And btw, is that WARN just a warning, or an error causing the program not to run?!

Comment: This link might help https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1372, the warning does seem as if something internally is blowing up, but like is your s3client not being properly created?

Comment: I'm not sure. My code shows how I created it.

Comment: Btw, I don't have any http client in pom or anywhere.

Comment: It must be a transitive dependency, you can see all dependencies by running ```mvn dependency:tree``` or just try to explicitly define org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9 in your project pom file.

Comment: Wow yes, at least the file size is working now. I added the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9` in pom and it fixed the issue!

Comment: @IlyaLapitan I really didnt expect it as it was just a WARN. You can write a response if you like and I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `warning` message there is a little bit misleading and technically should be `error` in this particular case as this is a breaking change in `httpclinet` library which can cause unexpected behavior of the program. This dependency itself comes as a transitive dependency from `aws-java-sdk`. So, to get it fixed just follow recommendation provided in the warning message and explicitly define the required version of `httpclinet`  in your project pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Alternatively, I added the line `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9` in pom and it fixed the issue!